# Netty handle large data, how to optimal?

Tags: netty

I implement like mail server based on netty, it receive some data about 160k size per message and one client connection send one message. so netty handle many short connection and large data.
In the case, Is there a more optimal way?
Maybe, many optimal option in netty configuration? I am new user for netty, kindly help me, thanks

Comment: If you have similar case, please share your optimize experience!

Comment: I used Netty4_CR9 to test short connection, send about 100000 message direct memory leak, OS is used 10G memory, is there any wrong?

Comment: Have you got any solution? I have even more sized message. Kindly share.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry about configurations upfront. It's hard to tune things before it's there! Netty is highly customizable so if you find something suboptimal, it should be easy to change things. The list would include using asynchronous IO vs. synchronous IO, threading strategy, serialization strategy, connection pooling etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will consider optimize from your given factor.